# notices when upgrade the php version

Tags: php, notice

i am using a class to make some calculations with matrices, in this case: **Get the sum of each column.**

The sum output is correct, and if I hide the notices,  the problem is solved, but logically, i prefer the correction.

In PHP 5.3 I get some notices in this function:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 
Notice: Undefined offset: 1
```

**script**

```
function sum()
    {
        foreach($this->numbers as $i => $rows)
        {
            foreach($rows as $j => $number)
            {
                $this->sum[0][$j] += $number; //notices here
            }
        }
        $the_sum = new matrix($this->sum, 1, $this->get_num_columns());

        return $the_sum;
    }
```

**Matrix:**

```
1     | 4

0.25  | 1



var_dump($this->numbers);
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => int 1
      1 => float 4
  1 => 
    array
      0 => float 0.25
      1 => int 1
```

and

```
 $this->get_num_columns() // 2
```

Any idea to correct these notices ?

thanks

Comment: Initialize `$this->sum` and `$this->sum[0]`.

Comment: A little remark: notices are not new to 5.3. Most likely, you've just changed your PHP settings when upgrading. Your current settings seem to be what you should have been using before :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the notice occurs because there is no initial value in the variables you are adding numbers to. You should check if the number exists and initialize it before you add a number to it. (Note, this won't improve your result, but it is good practice to initialize variables).

```
function sum()
    {
        foreach($this->numbers as $i => $rows)
        {
            foreach($rows as $j => $number)
            {
                if (!isset($this->sum[0][$j])) $this->sum[0][$j] = 0;
                $this->sum[0][$j] += $number; //no notices here
            }
        }
        $the_sum = new matrix($this->sum, 1, $this->get_num_columns());

        return $the_sum;
    }
```

---

### Unrelated Points to Consider

- Proper naming standards dictate that class name should be capitalized, to differentiate them from functions. So you should name your class `Matrix` and not `matrix`.
- If you get the chance, a much better solution would be to pre-fill your array with 0s. [`array_fill()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) does the job nicely.

Comment: Or, perhaps there is an earlier opportunity to initialize the `sum` array with zeroes using [array_fill()](http://php.net/array_fill).

Comment: That's an option as well, but I haven't seen that opening in the code, (I don't know how the class is constructed), so I let it go @Wiseguy. Valid point though.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said "perhaps".

Comment: Just to learn, i if i try: `$this->sum[0][$j] =array_fill(0, count($this->numbers), 0);` and after that: `$this->sum[0][$j] += $number;` i get Unsupported operand types

Comment: You are trying to use array_fill() on a single array element. You need to pass the whole array. Try `$this->sum[0]` or even `$this->sum` that will fill the ENTIRE array with 0.